# [Websphere liberty]- [API Discovery] : "CWWKO1204E: Can not have multiple operations with the same operation ID"

Tags: swagger, websphere-liberty

I have enabled apiDiscovery-1.0 feature on WebSphere liberty February 2016 beta.
It does not work if two methods have the same name even if this methods are in two different services.

```
Stack Dump = io.swagger.models.SwaggerException: CWWKO1204E: Impossible d'avoir plusieurs opérations avec le même ID opération : doGet
at io.swagger.models.Swagger.validateOperationIDs(Swagger.java:1001)
at io.swagger.models.Swagger.validate(Swagger.java:1020)
at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerResolver.resolve(SwaggerResolver.java:46)
at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.parse(SwaggerParser.java:121)
at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.parse(SwaggerParser.java:92)
at com.ibm.ws.rest.api.discovery.APIProviderAggregator.getSwaggerDoc(APIProviderAggregator.java:445)
```

As explained in the comments of this [article](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/02/17/exposing-liberty-rest-apis-swagger/), i have tried to use **nickname attribute of @ApiOperation but it does not work**. It seems that liberty embed a version of swagger older than 1.5.4 without this bug [resolution](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/commit/91a4dbef7c3756ecc69f334bd5d7a89ecf4b5737).

1. Is there a workaround to avoid this error ?
2. When Websphere Liberty will correct the nickname bug ?
3. Even if two same operationId is not valid in same swagger.json document,  swagger-ui works well with this kind of error. Could you remove the validation of swagger document and support non unique method name in same Liberty server ?

Comment: The `nickname` bug is now fix in WAS Liberty V8.5.5.9. You can download it from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

**Update** (08/29): The latest [Beta](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/) now support duplicate methods.

The quickest workaround for now is to modify the name of the methods that are causing this clash, as the name of those methods shouldn't impact your RESTful app's behavior.

As you have correctly noted, there is a tight integration with Swagger's Open Source model and parser, and the pattern so far is that Liberty Beta offerings pick-up bug fixes from the community (as well as pushing some patches out), so please keep an eye out for the next Beta!

There's definitely some more room for improvement here, as the comment in the [article](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/02/17/exposing-liberty-rest-apis-swagger/) you referenced suggested that a fully qualified method name could help solve this.  We're looking into this, and I will also take your non-valid-swagger-UI comment as feedback to the team.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I have the latest version (16.0.0.2) and faced this problem too.

Comment: Correct, version 16.0.0.2 still has this issue.  Look out for the September Beta in a few weeks from wasdev.net

Comment: September Beta indeed has the nickname fix!. However, I still wish apiDiscovery would work without this workaround. Is this a problem in swagger-core? or Liberty?

Comment: @nacho4d the [September Beta](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/) also now allows duplicate methods in the same jaxrs app.   Have you retried your original app?

Comment: If I have two methods `doPost` I get: `[WARNING ] CWWKO1102W: A Swagger object could not be created for APIProvider com.ibm.ws.rest.api.discovery.SwaggerWebProvider@17493d9d from document type Swagger_20_JSON due to class io.swagger.models.SwaggerException : CWWKO1204E: Can not have multiple operations with the same operation ID: doPost.` . Is this the September version? I just updated today and no more updates are showing in Eclipse: `Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 2016.7.0.0/wlp-1.0.13.20160626-0200) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_91-b14 (en_US)`

Comment: @nacho4d that's an older beta that you're using.  The latest [Beta](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/) shows: "WebSphere Application Server 2016.9.0.0/wlp-1.0.14.20160822-0201"

Comment: I have updated to 20160822 version. It works for duplicated methods!